# I am unable to login to my Ubuntu machine or reinstall

Tags: format

I started my laptop one day and I got a warning message before the login screen saying (Use/lib/libconf2-4/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256).

Trust me, I checked Google and all Ubuntu forums to find the answer to this before posting my issue here.

I found that many people have had the same issue but none of their sulutions worked for me.

**mostly cause:**

1. I can't login using gnome so I have to use the command line.
2. Everytime I `sudo` I get something about **soduers mode not being 0440** *(when I looked that up and tried to change the mode as some forums suggested, I got an error saying permission denied.)*
3. I tried to 'su to root' to fix that but then i get something about authentication being wrong!

So it looks quite shut from everywhere and I am REALLY lost.

I dont mind reinstalling Ubuntu and having all data erased, I already have everything saved on a hard drive, but when I put in the Ubuntu Install CD, it ejects it before booting from it and refuses to boot from any other CD as well.

Please help me out I have been trying for 3 weeks now and this is honestly my last resort .

Thank you so much in advance.

I love Ubuntu and I want it back.

Comment: This sounds like something happened to your `gconf` data, you can try to let him restore the default settings by moving the folder. Log in on the terminal and execute the following command `mv .gconf .gconf_backup` and then try to login again via GDM.

Comment: Nothing happend honestly, it still refuses to log in from the GDM !

Comment: Can you login using the command line and then run `startx`?

Comment: Judging from the sudoers file permissions change and the other random issues, it is likely that you have done a recursive permissions chnage (chmod -R something / ). Your best solution on this case is really the reinstall.

Comment: to trminal I can Already log in using my user name and passward it just refuses to give me any prevliges to preform any commands. I have just tried startx and it showed a log ending with (Fatal server error:server is alreday activefor desplay 0 ,if this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.x0-lock and start again

Comment: I wish I could reinstall It refuses to boot from any CD inclusing UBUNTU and MAC OSX it ejects any cd I put in.

Comment: But how do you install Ubuntu first time??

Comment: Can your laptop boot from a USB device?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your BIOS settings if you can't boot from a CD. Also, you might want to try burning another Ubuntu CD.

Comment: So greatful for the fast reply. I am using a macbook and i Have tried the Ubuntu Cd on many Other laptops and always worked perfectly, Also the apple OSX Cd isn't booting as well, So I am quite sure the issue isn't with the CD.

Comment: I suppose you already know that, but I seem to remember something about needing to hold down some key while booting from CD on a Mac...?

Comment: I guess [this](http://www.jacsoft.co.nz/Tech_Notes/Mac_Keys.shtml) might be useful.